# Cant append correctly div onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a php for loop which repeatedly renders div.

This is the for loop.Here  $checkboxitemsafterstripper is a single dimensional array

```
 foreach( $checkboxitemsafterstripper as $key => $item ){
    echo ' <form id="'.$item.'form"><div class="div-table" id="'.$item.'">
         <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div   class="c" id="add'.$item.'" data-value="'.$key.'"  >'
        }
```

I need to get the id of div and display subtables for this table using the jquery

The jquery i tried is here

In jquery tablemap a javascript array containing same elements as checkboxitemsafterstripper in php.

```
$('.c').click(function () {
       

var m=$(this).attr('data-value');
 

$("#add"+tablemap[m]).click(function(){




booleantable[m]=booleantable[m]+1;

var html='<div class="div-table-row">';
             html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
               html+=' <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash delete" id="delete'+tablemap[m]+m+'"></i></a></div>';
               html+='</div>';
  

$("#"+tablemap[m]+"form").append(html);
alert(html);
html="";



});


    });
```

The problem with this script is that it prints 1 subtable on first click 2 subtable on second click 3 subtable on third click of div.Why is this happening so.How can i make it one subtable on each consecutive click.

If this is a stupid question please excuse me or tell me i shall delete this question

Here  is the full php code https://pastebin.com/raw/cjFGgzGs

Answer (score 0):

The  simplest way I found was  to remove the lines  $("#add"+tablemap[m]).click(function(){
and the matching  });

that will set up one click handler for all .c buttons, present and future

```
 $('.c').click(function () {
       
 var m=$(this).attr('data-value');
 

{


    


booleantable[m]=booleantable[m]+1;

var html='<div class="div-table-row">';
             html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
               html+=' <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash delete" id="delete'+tablemap[m]+m+'"></i></a></div>';
               html+='</div>';
  

$("#"+tablemap[m]+"form").append(html);
alert(html);
html="";

}

});
```